# How to copy pictures from directory and subdirectory to another directory?

Tags: java

How can I copy pictures from directory that I wrote to console and subdirectory to another directory.

I have problem with getting directory from console.

This code works but when I change

```
private File[] images = new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures"+"/").listFiles()
```

with

```
new File(path+"/").listFiles()
```

its not working.

```
public class Copy {
    private String path;
    private File[] images = new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures"
            + "/").listFiles();

    private Copy() throws IOException {
        getPath();
        finder();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Copy copy = new Copy();
    }

    private void getPath() {
        System.out.print("Enter directory: ");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            path = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IO error trying to read your name!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void finder() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("" + path);
        for (File f : images) {

            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                File[] nextimages = new File(
                        "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures" + "/"
                                + f.getName()).listFiles();
                for (File z : nextimages) {
                    System.out.println("Processing: " + z.getName() + "...");
                    if (z.isHidden()) {
                        System.out.println("Skipping, file is hidden...");
                        continue;
                    }
                    process(z);
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (f.isHidden()) {
                System.out.println("Skipping, file is hidden...");
                continue;
            }
            process(f);

        }
    }

    private void process(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        saveThumbnail(file, image);
    }

    private void saveThumbnail(File originalFile, BufferedImage thumbnail)
            throws IOException {
        String filename = originalFile.getName();
        String fileExt = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, fileExt, new File("D:/Stahovanie/Zadanie/"
                + filename));
    }
}
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead? What's the point of creating a new file for the sub directory since you already have it in the variable `f`?

Comment: Have you tried to system.println(path) to see what are you getting?

Comment: How do you get input from console?

Comment: Check path value buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
private String path;
private File[] images = new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures"+"/").listFiles();
```

so at start `path` is `null`. Now you need to know that fields are initialized before constructors code, so if you change `images` to

```
new File(path+"/").listFiles();
```

it will be the same as changing it to

```
new File(null+"/").listFiles();
```

so it will produce

```
new File("null/").listFiles();
```

---

To solve that problem try invoking

```
images = new File(path+"/").listFiles();
```

when `path` will be set to correct value, so probably after `getPath` method.

Comment: thanks its working...could you please help with finder() problem...when directory has subdirectory and this directory has another subdirectory its broke down...how can i solve this problem??

Comment: @D3laru3 To solve subdirectories problem maybe change `finder` a little. Try adding argument like `finder(File directory)`. Now when you iterate over `listFiles` and find subdirectory invoke another `finder` for that subdirectory.